# How to write file in Windows Phone 7.1?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I would like to create an application for Windows Phone with Silverlight C#. This application needs to create a file (possibly editable only by the application who created it as in Android with the private mode). This file can be either on the SD card or, if it is possible, in the application package as in Android. The file must not be accessible by the user. I need to create also a file that the user may read so it would be better if I could put it on the SD card. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Isolated storage](http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-store-data-in-isolatedstoragesettings) is what you are looking for